# how to pass property from Soap UI to Json

Tags: json, automation, soapui

i try to pass a UUID parameter as defined in picture 1 to picture 2 below as mark as xxx. what to fill up as xxx in order to pass the UUID

## Picture 1

[image]

## Picture 2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're setting a test-case level property, so you'll be able to use the value elsewhere in the test case like this:

```
${#TestCase#uuid}
```

Where `#Testcase#` is the property level and `uuid` is the name of the property.